# Kendo Chart Missing CategoryAxis Text for multiple series

Tags: charts, kendo-ui, axis-labels

I am creating a kendo chart that can have multiple datasets.

I am creating a chartOptions object that is only being manipulated by referencing the properties and is not manipulated through Kendo functionality.  This is done by the following code:

```
var chartOptions = {
        theme: "",
        seriesDefaults: {
            type: "line"
        },
        title: {
            text: ""
        },
        legend: {
            position: "bottom"
        },
        series: "",
        categoryAxis: {
            field: "category"
        }
    };


function createChart() {
        $("#chart").kendoChart(
            $.extend(true, {}, chartOptions)
        );
    }
```

I also have the user defining which datasets they want.  The choose their datasets and create their chart.  The chart is then rendered but missing its categoryAxis data.

I am setting the series data (the data comes from the server, but is available for example) in the following way:

```
dataSetContents.Series = {"Series":[{"name":"2009 Data","data":[{"category":"2008","value":18159},{"category":"2007","value":315},{"category":"2009","value":8}]},{"name":"2008-2010","data":[{"category":"2010","value":750},{"category":"2009","value":2980},{"category":"2008","value":4135},{"category":"2007","value":55}]}]}

chartOptions.series = dataSetContents.Series;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured out the reason why I was losing my categories.  It has to do with the multiple series, the way to fix this by setting the categoryAxis.  This can be done by passing the array of categories like this:

```
chartOptions.categoryAxis = { categories: [2007,2008,2009,2010] };
```